# How to measure daily number of metrics which is written to the single MongoDB instance?

Tags: database, mongodb

Please suggest a commands to measure daily number of metrics which is written to the single MongoDB instance?

Answer (score 0):

"Daily number of metrics" is very broad, but the [`db.serverStatus()` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/) in the `mongo` shell (or the `serverStatus` command if you want to invoke this via a driver) is a great starting point for hundreds of metrics about your deployment.

The [`serverStatus` output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#output) will vary depending on your version of MongoDB, O/S, and deployment configuration. Common metrics include [opcounters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#opcounters) (database operations by type since the `mongod` instance started), [connections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#connections), and [memory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#mem) usage.

For more general informational and diagnostic commands, the list of [Database Commands used by the Cloud Manager Monitoring Agent](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/reference/monitoring/) is also a useful reference.